# How to check whether a file is hidden?

Tags: c#

```
File.SetAttributes((new FileInfo((new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath)).Name, FileAttributes.Hidden);
if(Check file Hidden )
....
else
()
```

I can not understand how to know that whether the file is hidden on the way

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Attributes` property of FileInfo class..

```
var fInfo = new FileInfo(..);
if (fInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
{

}
```

Answer (score 11):

For a single file operation prefer the `System.IO.File` static methods ( and for multiple operations on the same file `System.IO.FileInfo` ) :

```
bool isHidden1 = File.GetAttributes(path).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden);

//bool isHidden2 = (File.GetAttributes(path) & FileAttributes.Hidden) > 0; 
//bool isHidden3 = ((int)File.GetAttributes(path) & 2) > 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what you need:

```
bool isHidden = (File.GetAttributes(fileName) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
file.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)
```

Returns `true/false`